# Python renaming error "file not found" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-not-found

I have problem with my code. I'm fairly new to Python, but i'm trying to make a script to rename all files in a folder (+ subfolders) that are older than 3 years.
It works fine for files in the folder, but when it comes to files in the subfolders I get a "file not found" error.

Here is my code:

```
import sys, os.path, time, datetime

count = 0

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:

    thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)    
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(thefile))
    duration = today - modified_date

    if duration.days > 1095:
        old = filename
        new = 'old_' + old
        print(thefile, "Last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(thefile)), os.path.getmtime(thefile))
        count = count + 1
        os.renames(old, new)

print("number of old files: ", count)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the full path of file

Update

```
old = filename
new = 'old_' + old
```

to

```
old = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
new = os.path.join(dirname, 'old_' + filename)
```